# How do you make sure your are not on production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

From time to time I need to perform dangerous tasks on non-production environment from rails console. I always perform some double check to make sure that I'm not on production. What are your practices? Any tools/gems that could help me disable devastating queries on production?

```
Loading beta environment (Rails 6.0.3.4)
irb(main):001:0> Rails.env
=> "beta"
irb(main):002:0> Rails.env == 'beta'
=> true
irb(main):003:0> Order.delete_all
=> 3389
irb(main):004:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check for the environment first in the Controler or where you are going to run the devastating code.

```
if Rails.env.development?
    do_someting
else
    prevent_someting
end
```